# Where is the Nur Buat prayer from?

Tags: source-identification, dua

I have chanced upon this blog (link below) and found the Nur Buat prayer.

http://magicseaopen.blogspot.sg/2012/05/gift-from-god-nur-buat-prayer.html

I been searching for the past hour to find out which verse of the Quran is this from but I couldn't find the source. Can someone please point me to the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't exist in Quran. Its direction is:

[Bihar al-Anwar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihar_al-Anwar) by Allama Majlisi,volume 92,page 132

And it came from this event:

Once Angel Gabriel came to prophet and saw he was sad, so asked about its reason. The Prophet said because Hasan([Imam Hasan(a.s.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasan_ibn_Ali)) and Husayn([Imam Husayn(a.s.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husayn_ibn_Ali)) are sick from Sore eyes. Angel Gabriel said sore eyes are right;and to obviate it,read surah Al-Falaq and An-Nas, and read this Prayer.